Simplest way to wrap an "AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED" output around #ifndef and #endif?
This line for example
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([SOME_MACRO_NAME], "$SOME_VALUE", [some comment])

generates
printf "%s\n" "#define SOME_MACRO_NAME \"$SOME_VALUE\"" >>confdefs.h

as a line in configure.
And something like the following in config.h after configure is run:
/* some comment */
#define SOME_MACRO_NAME "<expanded value of $SOME_VALUE here>"

How would I make it produce the following instead?
/* some comment */
#ifndef SOME_MACRO_NAME
#define SOME_MACRO_NAME "<expanded value of $SOME_VALUE here>"
#endif

Surely I can add some printf lines manually or create a custom function but shouldn't there be an idiomatic way to do this already?  Either methods I mentioned are hackish either way as I'm asserting confdefs.h is the file being temporarily produced.
I'm already seeing people would be suggesting testing $SOME_VALUE maybe through AS_IF or m4_if (or any of their applicable variants) instead but that's a varying use case.  I might want to have the variable overridable through autoreconf, through ./configure or through CFLAGS with the -D option.  It depends.  But right now I just want the answer for this.
Also somebody might suggest using a template.  Please, please no.
